# __enable_irq() Intrinsic Infinite Loop

Tags: stm32, interrupts, assembly

I'm implementing a system based on the STM32L0 line of microcontrollers that uses an external interrupt to trigger an SPI read from an external sensor (a DW1000 UWB module). I am not running any sort of OS. The microcontroller runs through all of the initialization code, but just before I enter the infinite `while`, I want to enable interrupts, so I call the `__enable_irq()` intrinsic found in `CMSIS_gcc.h`. When the microcontroller enters into the function, it does not return, and the debugger outputs the following repeatedly:

> Performing single step...
> ...Target halted (DBGRQ, PC = 0x0800460C)
> Reading all registers

The disassembly looks like this:

```
 __ASM volatile ("cpsie i" : : : "memory");
0800460a:   cpsie   i
0800460c:   b.n     0x800460c <main+144>
0800460e:   bl      0x80043f4 <Error_Handler>
08004612:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
08004614:   ldr     r0, [r0, r0]
08004616:   ands    r1, r0
08004618:   asrs    r0, r0, #32
0800461a:   ands    r2, r0
0800461c:   b.n     0x8004640 <RTC_IRQHandler+4>
0800461e:   b.n     0x8004622 <main+166>
08004620:   ldrb    r7, [r7, #31]
08004622:           ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xffff0764
08004626:   movs    r0, #0
```

I'm thinking the line at address 0x800460c is suspicious because it shouldn't be attempting to branch to itself, but I am having a hard time understanding the programming manual and the `.n` suffix of the `b` instruction. The C-code follows:

```
  /* Ensures IRQs are only enabled once. */
  prim = __get_PRIMASK();
  if(!(prim & 0x01)){
      __enable_irq();
  }


...

__attribute__( ( always_inline ) ) __STATIC_INLINE void __enable_irq(void)
{
  __ASM volatile ("cpsie i" : : : "memory");
}
```

Any direction is helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't analysed the assembly code so this may be incorrect. But, I suspect your code is entering an ISR but that routine isn't clearing the interrupt flag. So, the ISR finishes and is immediately triggered again... and again...

Comment: From the [ARM Documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/instruction-width-specifiers): `In Thumb code the .N width specifier forces the assembler to generate a 16-bit encoding.`. So that's part isn't particularly suspicious.

Comment: I agree with @bitsmack here, yet I think an interrupt occurs (or has already occured) which wasn't setup properly (i.e. no interrupt handler defined).

Answer (score 1):

I was performing all of my computations (full TDoA multilateration algorithm) inside the ISR, which was most likely overflowing the stack. I moved the algorithm outside the ISR and instead saved the data in a FIFO to process later. This solved the issue. Thank you all for the suggestions, they were very helpful in investigating the interrupt!